# SQL Server Upgrade + BPE

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2019

One of the SQL instance has BPE( buffer pool extension) enabled. Would this have an impact ( or any issues ) if instance is upgraded from SQL 2014 to SQL 2019. I went through the MS docs and does not state any such limitations.

Any info on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

At the least, the Microsoft Books Online for [Editions and supported features of SQL Server 2019 (15.x)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2019?view=sql-server-ver16) state that the Buffer Pool Extension feature is still available in SQL Server 2019 in both the [RDBMS scalability and performance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2019?view=sql-server-ver16#RDBMSSP) and [RDBMS manageability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2019?view=sql-server-ver16#RDBMSM) sections. This is true for both Standard and Enterprise editions.